# Matlab fzero command usage

Tags: matlab, calculus

I am trying to approximate a solution for the equation `x+sin(x) = -e^x` around the point `x=-2`. I used the line:

```
fzero('x+sin(x) == -exp(x)', -2);
```

However, this gave me the wrong answer. I believe my mistake was using a `==` in the expression and it should be:

```
fzero('x+sin(x)+exp(x)', -2);
```

Could anyone explain the reasoning behind this?

Comment: In addition to the answer, you shouldn't be using strings unless your version of Matlab is 10 years old. Please read the documentation/help for `fzero` and learn about anonymous functions and function handles: `fzero(@(x)x+sin(x)+exp(x), -2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote the [MATLAB documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html):

> `x = fzero(fun,x0)` tries to find a point `x` where `fun(x) = 0`.

`fzero` doesn't reorder your equations for you, it can only calculate the [root or zero of a given function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_of_a_function).

Answer (score -7):

The answer lies in the name of the function. fzero(f,p) finds where
`f == 0` around the point p.

For your first example you are asking when `x+sin(x) == -exp(x)`. When this is true the function you provided will output 1 which will make fzero output any value other than the answer you want.

Comment: You can't calculate the solution to any equation just by subtracting 1 and using `fzero` to find the root, since `fzero` looks for sign changes, which are not going to occur (the result of the comparison can either be true or false, but not negative).

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me: *"When this is true the function you provided will output 1 which will make fzero output any value other than the answer you want."*. Can you clarify what you mean by this? In all honestly, this smells like cow manure.

Comment: This is probably the most hilarious way to negate 500 years of algebra.